# JavaScript changes not showing in Github

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, visual-studio-code, github-pages

I went back to one of my old apps https://github.com/Darkstar93/Warcraft-Quiz I made using a lot of Javscript/jQuery. Since It was so old (2016) the entire thing used VAR instead of the newer standard of Const/Let strings.

I've updated the code in VS Code and made the commits to Github. When I open the files in GitHub it shows the changes made to the var's. But when I try and look at the Page site in DevTools in the browser it only shows the old code.

What step am I missing to make sure the new code is updated on the Page?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see new commits on the [`master` branch](https://github.com/Darkstar93/Warcraft-Quiz/commits/master), but not on the [`gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/Darkstar93/Warcraft-Quiz/commits/gh-pages).

Depending on your [publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site), your GitHub Pages site ([`darkstar93.github.io/Warcraft-Quiz`](http://darkstar93.github.io/Warcraft-Quiz/)) might only take its source from the latter branch (`gh-pages`). which was *not* updated.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I've gone into the publishing source and changed it back and forth from master to gh-pages. Both files have been updated to the new code, but the page has not reflected any changes. Is there a significant delay? The deployments say that it's active and current.

Comment: Oop it looks like there was just a few minutes delay It's finally reflecting the new code strings. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ThomasT. Yes, there can be a slight delay between source code modification and page rendering.